# Algolia Historical SDK's License Key

Tags: java, android, api-key, license-key, algolia

I'm trying to use Algolia's Offline SDK for Android. In the documentation, it states that I need to place my License key into the `offlineIndex.initLibrary("licenseKey");` method.

I checked my credentials, and used both my Search-only API key and Admin Key, but neither one works.

Do I have to pay for the service (I'm currently on their trial version) in order to get a license key? I can't seem to find the answer anywhere on Algolia's site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This offline SDK is discontinued, today we recommend Android developers to use our [InstantSearch Android](https://github.com/algolia/instantsearch-android) library to build your apps.

We also provide an [Android API Client](https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-client-android), but you should prefer InstantSearch as it's easier and faster to build an application with it.

Comment: are there any examples on how to use the online sdk with Android's AutoCompleteTextView ?

Comment: @EbadSaghar: There is currently no example with `AutoCompleteTextView`, but you can take the `OnItemClickListener` and call `searcher.search()` with the selected text.